# Unknown entity because property is an interface

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have created one `User` interface. I have another class named `FinanceReport` that have a user property like this `private User user`. I use JPA an so I have annotated the FinanceReport class with the necessary attributes. I have one implementation of the `User` interface at the moment named `FinanceUser`.

Now, I am not able to deploy to server since I use `User` as an property. It tells me that it is an unknown entity...and that is right, the interface does not have the annotations such as `@Entity` etc.

I have a own Maven project for the user related classes and then the other Maven projects use the interface instead of a particular implementation.

Comment: I think there is no way to sign a field as no column, but why don't you use of another method? keep the User instance in another class and access it

Comment: JPA doesnt support interface fields as persistent, but some JPA implementations (e.g DataNucleus JPA) do allow it. You make no mention of which JPA implementation you use.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to persist the property, annotate it with `@Transient`, if you do need to persist it then you need to properly annotate User with `@Entity` etc. Also I'm not sure if you can do that with an interface as JPA provider will have to be smart enough to detect implementation of the interface

Comment: You are right that he cannot map interfaces as @Entity at all using JPA or Hibernate. Perhaps he could create an abstract class User and make it an Entity or MappedSuperclass.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to map the interface relationship, see,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Interfaces